# I am trying to combine columns in dynamically bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have data **input** :

```
firstname   middlename  lastname    Tag_state   Tag_country
Jhon                     smith         DC         US
Mary        Jhon         watson     Seattle       US
Harry                   potter                    US
```

**Output**:

```
firstname   middlename  lastname    Tag
Jhon                     smith    {'Tag_state': 'DC','Tag_country':'US'}
Mary           Jhon      watson   {'Tag_state': 'Seattle','Tag_country':'US'}
Harry                    potter    {'Tag_state': '','Tag_country':'US'}
```

How can combine column dynamically if column name starts with Tags combine it in json format.

Can you please help me.?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """ 
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
with temp as (
  select format('%t', t) row_id, 
    split(key, '_')[offset(0)] key, 
    split(key, '_')[safe_offset(1)] attr, 
    value 
  from your_table t, unnest(get_keys(to_json_string(t))) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(to_json_string(t))) value with offset using(offset)
)
select any_value(t).* except(row_id, attr, Tag), 
  concat('{', string_agg(format('"%s":"%s"', attr, Tag)), '}') as Tag 
from (
  select * from temp
  pivot (any_value(value) for key in ('Tag', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'))
) t
group by t.row_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
  select 'Jhon' firstname, '' middlename, 'smith' lastname, 'DC' Tag_state, 'US' Tag_country union all
  select 'Mary', 'Jhon', 'watson', 'Seattle', 'US' union all
  select 'Harry', '', 'potter', '', 'US'
```

output is

[image]

To make sure above works at least for sample data in your question - run exactly below query w/o ANY modification!!!

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """ 
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
with your_table as (
  select 'Jhon' firstname, '' middlename, 'smith' lastname, 'DC' Tag_state, 'US' Tag_country union all
  select 'Mary', 'Jhon', 'watson', 'Seattle', 'US' union all
  select 'Harry', '', 'potter', '', 'US'   
), temp as (
  select format('%t', t) row_id, 
    split(key, '_')[offset(0)] key, 
    split(key, '_')[safe_offset(1)] attr, 
    value 
  from your_table t, unnest(get_keys(to_json_string(t))) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(to_json_string(t))) value with offset using(offset)
)
select any_value(t).* except(row_id, attr, Tag), 
  concat('{', string_agg(format('"%s":"%s"', attr, Tag)), '}') as Tag 
from (
  select * from temp
  pivot (any_value(value) for key in ('Tag', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'))
) t
group by t.row_id
```

Comment: UDF worker Excecution timedout

Comment: are you running in BigQuery console? and with data sample you provided?

Comment: yes, I am running in bigquery console is there any way we can do it by sql rather than javascript

Comment: have you tried first with sample data you provided?! please try and confirm if it works or not, so we can troubleshoot further to figure out where the problem is

Comment: yes , that is the sample data that I have tried. that is so weird why it is not working

Comment: can you please help me with this.

Comment: added whole query along with sample data  - please run EXACTLY as is w/o any modification - and let know result!

Comment: This only works with 2 rows but if pass to large table it will fail… query is not optimised.. can you help me with that